# objective c Facebook Account Kit how to hide back button?

Tags: objective-c, facebook, account-kit

I'm using Facebook Account Kit.

So, I do not need the back button on the first screen (the text field with phone number). There is a simple way to hide back button or even navigation bar?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Advanced UI Manager to update the header in the experience:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/ios/customizing#advanced